# Ruby version not identified on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, version

I have just installed the latest Ruby version with HomeBrew, but I still get "ruby 2.0.0p481" from the terminal when I type "Ruby --version". I'm using a MacBook Air 10.9.5 (Mavericks). How do I fix this? It would be awesome if you could give me a step-by-step solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is quite probably that you're still using the ruby version that ships with MacOS (the one under `/usr/bin/ruby`) rather than the one installed by homebrew (which is under `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

First, check which version you're actually using by executing the following command in the terminal:

```
which ruby
```

If this says `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of `/usr/local/bin/ruby`, you can add the following at the end of your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to allow the terminal to use the executables from `/usr/local/bin` over `/usr/bin`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Now if you open a new terminal window, `which ruby` should point to the one installed by homebrew

Answer (score 2):

Better to use some ruby environment management utilities any of specified [here](https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby#environment-management)

I personally suggest you to use rbenv or rvm, it works very well with Mac-book.

Answer (score 0):

If you use zsh, try rehash. Otherwise I think `$PATH` is the cause.
Check it out, `echo $PATH | ruby -ne 'puts $_.split(":")'`